# Can a sound frequency 'not' within human hearing (20 Hz - 20 kHz) damage hearing when it is of high volume?

Tags: human-biology, hearing

We can't hear sounds outside the range of  20 Hz - 20 kHz. However, if an inaudible sound is played at high volume, will one's hearing be affected?

Comment: i think i found an interesting reference here... see the linked question